# Which Android versions support Snackbars?

Tags: android

The android.com site about snackbars (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) says: added in version 22.2.0

So do I need to check for Api 22 or 23?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add support for Snackbar in the gradle to work for lower APIs.

Add the following in dependencies of gradle and sync it:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

You do not need to check for version.

Answer (score 2):

The Android Design Support Library supports it for Android 2.1 and higher (API 7).